# Play Framework + SecureSocial : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: securesocial.controllers.ReverseLoginPage.authenticate

Tags: playframework, securesocial

I'm new to using the Play Framework, and I'm trying to incorporate the SecureSocial plugin into my app with a Facebook-OAuth2 provider. I ran into this error when I sent a GET request to `/login` :

```
! @6apkmf9m3 - Internal server error, for request [GET /login] ->

play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1$$anon$1: Execution exception [[NoSuchMethodError: securesocial.controllers.ReverseLoginPage.authenticate(Ljava/lang/String;)Lplay/api/mvc/Call;]]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:134) [play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.2]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:115) [play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.apply(Actor.scala:318) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker.apply(Invoker.scala:113) [play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:626) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:197) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: securesocial.controllers.ReverseLoginPage.authenticate(Ljava/lang/String;)Lplay/api/mvc/Call;
    at securesocial.core.IdentityProvider.authenticationUrl(IdentityProvider.scala:86) ~[classes/:na]
    at securesocial.views.html.login$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(login.template.scala:44) ~[classes/:na]
    at securesocial.views.html.login$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(login.template.scala:43) ~[classes/:na]
    at play.templates.TemplateMagic$.defining(ScalaTemplates.scala:756) ~[templates_2.9.1.jar:2.0.2]
    at securesocial.views.html.login$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(login.template.scala:43) ~[classes/:na]
    at securesocial.views.html.login$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(login.template.scala:42) ~[classes/:na]
```

- Could someone give me a hint on where to look to find more info about this error?
- How does Play work to go from `securesocial.controllers.ReverseLoginPage` to `securesocial.controllers.LoginPage`, with the former existing in the module?

Comment: Looks like the error is in the login template. Could you paste that, too?

Comment: is it the template use by securesocial ? https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/blob/master/module-code/app/securesocial/views/login.scala.html

Comment: Did you copy the SecureSocial routes into your app's routes file? Check the user guide at http://www.securesocial.ws and make sure you follow what's described there.

Comment: Gold rule, clone secure social project from Github repository and modify it, 
I have done the same thing and believe me it's very simple.
I assume that you are starting a new project.

Answer (score 4):

From the [Play 2 documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/ScalaRouting):

> For each controller used in the routes file, the router will generate
>   a ‘reverse controller’ in the routes package, having the same action
>   methods, with the same signature, but returning a play.api.mvc.Call
>   instead of a play.api.mvc.Action.

I think that's where the `ReverseLoginPage` is coming from, but I have no clue what's failing. Maybe some error in the routes, or an old class that's still around. Try running `clean`, just to be sure that that's not it.

Answer (score 0):

Even I am new to play framework. I cannot why right now but this has to do with your routes files. It is because securesocial is trying to invoke an action whose route is not given in your config. Try  this sample route, may be try debugging by removing the routes which you think are unnecessary one by one to get THE one route you are missing.

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()




# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)

# Login page
GET     /login                      securesocial.controllers.LoginPage.login
GET     /logout                     securesocial.controllers.LoginPage.logout

# User Registration and password handling (only needed if you are using UsernamePasswordProvider)
GET     /signup                     securesocial.controllers.Registration.startSignUp
POST    /signup                     securesocial.controllers.Registration.handleStartSignUp
GET     /signup/:token              securesocial.controllers.Registration.signUp(token)
POST    /signup/:token              securesocial.controllers.Registration.handleSignUp(token)
GET     /reset                      securesocial.controllers.Registration.startResetPassword
POST    /reset                      securesocial.controllers.Registration.handleStartResetPassword
GET     /reset/:token               securesocial.controllers.Registration.resetPassword(token)
POST    /reset/:token               securesocial.controllers.Registration.handleResetPassword(token)
GET     /password                   securesocial.controllers.PasswordChange.page
POST    /password                   securesocial.controllers.PasswordChange.handlePasswordChange


# Providers entry points
GET     /authenticate/:provider     securesocial.controllers.ProviderController.authenticate(provider)
POST    /authenticate/:provider     securesocial.controllers.ProviderController.authenticateByPost(provider)
GET     /not-authorized             securesocial.controllers.ProviderController.notAuthorized
```

It works for me with play 2.2.0 version and secure social is at master-SNAPSHOT.